# Why do I always have to reattach each transaction?

Tags: transaction, pending, reattach

I use a light wallet to make transactions in IOTA (Android Wallet + Windows wallet in Light Mode). When I make a transaction, I always need to reattach my transaction to the system to be confirmed (I tried a lot of full node addresses, but i have the same behaviour). I know that the Trinity wallet will do that automatically, but why? it doesn't make sense to me. Why do we have to do that ?
If the number of transactions was higher, should we do that too?

Answer (score 3):

According to [How does reattaching a transaction increase the chance for confirmation?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-reattaching-a-transaction-increase-the-chance-for-confirmation) two main reasons can be identified:

1. Your computer takes a lot of time for the POW, which results in an attach position not in front of the tangle. Thus other tx will not pickup your tx. (see also [Does the tip selection depend on how quickly the proof of work is done?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/758/does-the-tip-selection-depend-on-how-quickly-the-proof-of-work-is-done) and [Why does the tip-selection prefer new tips?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/718/why-does-the-tip-selection-prefer-new-tips))
2. Two tips may have been chosen that now belong to an invalid part of the tangle. This can be caused by your tx A confirming a tx B which was also reattached, but the reattached B' was picked up by the COO and confirmed. Thus your tx A attached to B is confirming the double-spend of B'.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you should do this to increase the chance of the validation, because you have more than one transaction. This transaction reference to other transaction, but is still a new transaction. Another issue are invalid transactions. If your transaction get confirmed by other, invalid transactions, your transaction will not confirmed anymore, because your transaction is within a parasite graph. It can then take much time until your transaction will confirmed.

This is what I interpreted currently. But I don't know if I'm correct.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a great article : http://untangled.world/iota-consensus/

It explains a lot of things !

Comment: In addition to referencing an article, it is always good to give a brief summary.